# Applications on macbook pro close waking computer up after 1 hour lunch

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

It's lunch time at work and I put my macbook in screen saver mode by using a hot corner. I return back to wake my computer up, and type in my password to resume work (I have the `require password immediately after sleep or screen saver begins` option checked.)
I then realise none of my applications are active whatsoever and it looks like a fresh restart has occurred.

I can confirm that: `System Preferences > Security >> General >>> Log out after ... minutes of activity` is not checked.

This is what my `pmset -g` look like:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                1
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 tcpkeepalive         1
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

**Can someone please help me fix this unwanted applications closing after my macbook pro goes to sleep when I return from lunch?**

Additional information:
I can confirm that I also have two external monitors connected to my laptop via mini display ports, as well as an Anker usb host.

I have macOS High Sierra installed version: 10.13.4 (17E199)

I have a macbook pro Retina, 15 inch Mid 2015.

Not in clamshell mode.

Comment: Does this happen when you disconnect all external devices before invoking the hot corner and leave the MBP in the same state? Are _other_ devices connected through the Anker host?

Comment: It might have done a restart to complete an installation involving a kernel update.  Have a look in "App Store"  in the updates pane to see the installation history.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That's not the case here.

Comment: @IconDaemon I'm not sure, I can try. I can try though what would the answer tell us? And I'd rather not have to experience this again while working - it affects my flow and application states.

Comment: Its a troubleshooting step to determine if these devices are the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's going on with your settings, but I think you will find that `caffeinate` can prevent this behavior. At a terminal screen, type `man caffeinate` to learn about the utility. An option that may work for you is this:

> caffeinate -s

Alternatively, if you have an application you wish to run while you are away from your Mac, you can use this form:

> caffeinate -w PID &

where `PID` is the process ID of the app that's running (available via Activity Monitor, or `ps -la`), and `&` for running in background.